# How should I make members of a collection aware of their "siblings" in relationship to their position

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, generics

**Context:**

Recently I have been working on several simple WPF projects to get more familiar with C# and XAML. They have mostly been recreations of old or simple games such as Minesweeper, Centipede, and Pong. I have decided to up the ante by recreating the SEGA Genesis game *Fatal Labyrinth* but I have hit a road block in the generation of the labyrinth.

The program works by generating a List of `<Cell>` which is a class I made that will act as the foundation for tracking the position of entities, the player, and the labyrinth itself. My first issue I encountered was the fickleness of 2D lists, so I decided that the easiest way to fix it would be to create my own generic type `Grid<T>` which consists of its Dimensions, an int for X and Y respectively, and a List of `GridItem<T>`, `GridItem<T>` being its own generic class.

`GridItem<T>` contains its position, given by X and Y coordinates that represent its location in the grid(These are not to be confused with the X and Y dimensions of `Grid` which represent the actual size of `Grid`) and the actual item of type `T`

**The Problem**
It would be immensely convenient if I could include a HasTop/HasNorth Boolean in `GridItem` as well as a TopNeighbor/NorthNeighbor (all of which would be of type `T` naturally) that way from one member of the grid, I can reference its neighbors directly without having to first confirm that it even has a neighbor and then perform a look up to get what it is. The other problem is that when I set one of the items inside of `GridItem` I once again have to perform a lookup through Linq and then set it. While I can use Linq, and while it would work, it is extremely bulky and hideous to look at and write.

**Attempted Solutions**
The first solution I tried was to just put a neighbor for every direction in the `GridItem` but the problem is the `GridItem`s in the actual grid and the `GridItem`s that are stored as neighbors do not update eachother.

The next natural solution flowing from that was to include in their get and set methods something that would appropriately update them all, and the chain would natural ripple out from there. The problem is that can only work one way because the `GridItem` is not aware of the `Grid` in which it is a member.

Very well, the next thing I tried was to just include the `Grid` of which the `GridItem` was a member inside the `GridItem` as a property entitled Parent. This unfortunately creates the "I am my own grandpa issue" as well as encountering the same ripple and recursion problems that would occur in the previous attempted solution.

**Answer I am looking for**

How can I make `GridItem` aware of the adjacent `GridItem`s such that it can both get and set them without creating recursive updating or "I am my own Grandpa"

**Bonus**

Also, if anyone can tell me how to make `T` only acceptable as a nullable type. For instance I want it to allow things like my `Cell` which can be returned as null but not Int or Bool which can't be null

**Edit:**
some people asked for the code so here it is:

```
public class Grid<T> where T : new()
{
    #region Constructors
    public Grid() { }
    public Grid(List<T> input, int RowLength, int ColumnLength)
    {
        XDimension = RowLength;
        YDimension = ColumnLength;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        input = input.Take(RowLength * ColumnLength).ToList();
        foreach (T item in input)
        {
            Items.Add(new GridItem<T> { Item = item, Position = new Coordinate { X = (UInt32)x, Y = (UInt32)y } });
            x += 1;
            if (x >= RowLength)
            {
                y += 1;
                x = 0;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < RowLength * ColumnLength - Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(new GridItem<T> { Item = new T(), Position = new Coordinate { X = (UInt32)x, Y = (UInt32)y }, SystemGenerated = true });
            x += 1;
            if (x >= RowLength)
            {
                y += 1;
                x = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
    public enum NeigborSelectionEnum { Top, Bottom, Left, Right };
    private List<GridItem<T>> items = new List<GridItem<T>>();
    private int xDimension;
    private int yDimension;
    public List<GridItem<T>> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }

        set
        {
            items = value;
        }
    }
    public int XDimension
    {
        get
        {
            return xDimension;
        }

        set
        {
            xDimension = value;
        }
    }
    public int YDimension
    {
        get
        {
            return yDimension;
        }

        set
        {
            yDimension = value;
        }
    }
    public T NeighborOf(NeigborSelectionEnum selectedNeighbor, Coordinate position)
    {
        switch (selectedNeighbor)
        {
            case NeigborSelectionEnum.Top:
                if (position.Y > 0)
                {
                    return Items.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Position.X == position.X && n.Position.Y == position.Y - 1).Item;
                }
                return default(T);
            case NeigborSelectionEnum.Bottom:
                if (position.Y + 1 < YDimension)
                {
                    return Items.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Position.X == position.X && n.Position.Y == position.Y + 1).Item;
                }
                return default(T);
            case NeigborSelectionEnum.Left:
                if (position.X > 0)
                {
                    return Items.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Position.X == position.X - 1 && n.Position.Y == position.Y).Item;
                }
                return default(T);
            case NeigborSelectionEnum.Right:
                if (position.X + 1 < XDimension)
                {
                    return Items.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Position.X == position.X + 1 && n.Position.Y == position.Y).Item;
                }
                return default(T);
            default:
                return default(T);
        }
    }
    public T NeighborOf(NeigborSelectionEnum selectedNeighbor, GridItem<T> item)
    {
        UInt32 x = item.Position.X;
        UInt32 y = item.Position.Y;
        switch (selectedNeighbor)
        {
            case NeigborSelectionEnum.Top:
                if (y > 0)
                {
                    return Items.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Position.X == x && n.Position.Y == y - 1).Item;
                }
                return default(T);
            case NeigborSelectionEnum.Bottom:
                if (y + 1 < YDimension)
                {
                    return Items.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Position.X == x && n.Position.Y == y + 1).Item;
                }
                return default(T);
            case NeigborSelectionEnum.Left:
                if (x > 0)
                {
                    return Items.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Position.X == x - 1 && n.Position.Y == y).Item;
                }
                return default(T);
            case NeigborSelectionEnum.Right:
                if (x + 1 < XDimension)
                {
                    return Items.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Position.X == x + 1 && n.Position.Y == y).Item;
                }
                return default(T);
            default:
                return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the `GridItem`

```
public class GridItem<T> where T : new()
{
    private T item;
    private Coordinate position;
    private bool systemGenerated = false;
    public T Item
    {
        get
        {
            return item;
        }

        set
        {
            item = value;
        }
    }
    public Coordinate Position
    {
        get
        {
            return position;
        }

        set
        {
            position = value;
        }
    }
    public bool SystemGenerated
    {
        get
        {
            return systemGenerated;
        }

        set
        {
            systemGenerated = value;
        }
    }
    public Grid<T> Parent
    {
        get
        {
            return parent;
        }

        set
        {
            parent = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and at present the code is messy from trying to work it out in places other than the class so I can't give you that. However a good example I could give you would be:

```
List<Cell> MazeMakeStack = new List<Cell>().Add(CellGrid.Items[0, new Random().Next(0,CellGrid.Items.Count-1)]);
do
{
    List<string> availableCells = new List<string>();
    //Checks the Top neighbor of the `CellGrid` who's Item.Id == MazeMakeStack.Last().Id and checks the Boolean IsVistited which is false by default
    if (!IsVisited)
    {
        availableCells.Add("Top")
    }
    //repeats this for left, bottom, and right adding them to availableCells respectively
    if(availableCells.Count=<0)
    {
        //resolves the borders of the cell and then removes it from the stack such that the next item can be handled
        //(My method is randomized depth first search so this is when the tree has no places to go)
    }
    else
    {
        //randomly chooses a member of availableCells
        //uses a switch that tests the randomly chosen member of availableCells and then based on that grabs the corresponding neighbor, adding it MazeMakerStack
    }
}
while(MazeMakeStack,Count()>0)
```

Comment: Bonus, use the class filter on the generic type, where T : class

Comment: Can you post your code? Seeing your classes and methods you have tried would be helpful. FYI you can restrict generics as Mike points out with a where clause: `public class MyClass<T> where T : class` will force T to be a class type rather than a simple type.

Comment: What is this "I am my own granda" issue you are having? Linking back to the parent grid inside a Griditem seems like a sensible solution; the grid can store all GridItems in a 2d array (or a sparse array / dictionary if most cells are empty) and then each GridItem can easily look up its neighbours on demand by querying the parent grid. (small drawback: you would have to update the grid as well as the GridItem when you change the position)

Comment: @HugoRune The problem is that if a GridItem contains the grid, It also contains itself. Therefore, when a GridItem would update, it would update the grid, which would update the item, which would update the grid, which would update the item. Its like having a list be a member of itself

Answer (score 0):

Because the `GridItem<T>` class does not know about any other `GridItem<T>` items that are in the `Grid<T>`, you could use a delegate to achieve your goal.

Here is an example:

#### Grid Class:

```
public class Grid<T>
{
    int width;
    int height;
    public List<GridItem<T>> Cells { get; set; }

    public Grid()
    {
        foreach (GridItem<T> cell in Cells)
        {
            cell.onGetNeighbor += OnGetNeighbor;
        }
    }

    private GridItem<T> OnGetNeighbor(GridItem<T> self, Direction direction)
    {
        GridItem<T> neighbor = null;

        switch (direction)
        {
            case Direction.Top:
                neighbor = Cells.FirstOrDefault(cell => 
                    cell.X == self.X && cell.Y == self.Y - 1);
                break;
            case Direction.Bottom:
                neighbor = Cells.FirstOrDefault(cell =>
                    cell.X == self.X && cell.Y == self.Y + 1);
                break;
            case Direction.Left:
                neighbor = Cells.FirstOrDefault(cell =>
                    cell.X == self.X - 1 && cell.Y == self.Y);
                break;
            case Direction.Right:
                neighbor = Cells.FirstOrDefault(cell =>
                    cell.X == self.X + 1 && cell.Y == self.Y);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return neighbor;
    }
}
```

#### GridItem Class:

```
public class GridItem<T>
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Func<GridItem<T>, Direction, GridItem<T>> onGetNeighbor;

    public GridItem<T> GetNeighbor(Direction direction)
    {
        return onGetNeighbor(this, direction);
    }
}
```

#### Direction Enum:

```
public enum Direction
{
    Top, Bottom, Left, Right
}
```

You can use this like so:

```
// Insert your grid/grid item code here ..
Grid<int> grid = new Grid<int>();
GridItem<int> item = grid.Cells[1];

// Get top neighbor
GridItem<int> neighbor = item.GetNeighbor(Direction.Top);

// Check if top neighbor exists
bool topNeighborExists = item.GetNeighbor(Direction.Top) != null;
```

Comment: I like your solution, but my experience with delegates is low. What your saying is that I should make the get method and set method of the Neighbors contained within GridItem call the delegate in Grid which will take the position of the GridItem that fired the delegate and an enum that dictates which direction to look in and then from there return the actual GridItem or set the actual GridItem instead of ever having the neighbors be inside the GridItem itself?

Comment: You have the right idea. Technically, the delegate is on the `GridItem<T>` class itself, and then you are _"plugging"_ a method into it in the `Grid<T>` class, so that whenever that delegate is called, it will run the method that you plugged into it.